# Date comparision with converting string to date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

how to change string to time with time 
i am wring code as but no luck

```
NSString *comingdate = [sParams valueForKey:@"showdate"];
NSDateFormatter *dateformate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *todate = [dateformate dateFromString:comingdate];
NSLog(@"%@", todate);
```

/* from showdate i am getting date as yyyy-MM-dd but i awant to convert that string to date with time 
 can any one give the clue or with clear code

Comment: If you want to get the full date/time you need to specify a date format that includes the layout of both date and time (consistent with your input string's format).  What does your full input string look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDate *firstDate=[[NSDate alloc]init];
    NSString *comingdate = [sParams valueForKey:@"showdate"]; // yyyy-MM-dd
    NSString *time = @"01:37:42"; // HH:mm:ss
    comingdate = [comingdate stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", time];
    NSDateFormatter *dateformate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateformate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *secondDate = [dateformate dateFromString:comingdate];
    NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];
    NSLog(@"%f",timeDifference);
```